# How to dynamically add tag (latitude, longitude) in XML file when I click on Google map

Tags: xml, google-maps

I want to store latitude-longitude in XML file, when user clicked on google map. and also create XML file dynamically (if file not exist, create and add tags, OR if exist then append the tag).

```
<root>
     <point> 
            <latitude>  27.4324 </latitude>
            <longitude> 73.4422 </longitude>
     </point>
        .
        .
        .
</root>
```

thanks...

Comment: What code have you tried so far that isn't working?  What server-side language are you using (PHP, ASP.NET, ColdFusion, etc.)?  What version of the Google Maps API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, you'll need to perform an AJAX request to a server-side script that performs the creation/update of the XML file on the map.click() event, passing the latitude and longitude to the script.  Without knowing what server-side language you're using, what version of the Google Maps API you're using, and what you've already tried, it's difficult to be more specific.